# Error When Downloading Files from flask on Linux Server

Tags: python, windows, flask

My code works perfectly on my windows machine:

```
@app.route('/downloads/<filename>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def downloads(filename):
    return send_file(filename, as_attachment=True)
```

It uses  tags to pass the variable through for each specific item in a list on an html page. On my windows machine i specify the filename (Which is the directory for the file) variable with backslash's (which then translate into '%5C' in the search bar for whatever reason). This works fine but when i run the same code on my linux machine it gives me an "Internal Server Error" on the browser and this error in the server.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/ss/python_files\\user\\file.py'
```

Now i understand that Linux uses 'forward slashes' for directories and Windows uses 'back slashes' for whatever reason and i figured this was the error but when i try to use 'forward slashes' in the directory instead it gives me a 404 error in the browser:

'Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.'

And it gives me this in the server:

```
"GET /downloads/python_files/user/file.py HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Which would make you think that maybe I just have the wrong path to the file, but when I go into the same directory as the server's python file and type:

```
python3 python_files/user/file.py
```

It runs the file, so its nothing wrong with the path...
Anyways this is where I became stumped and realized I don't have enough knowledge to fix the error. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: enter `pwd` command where you run your app, and also use it where you have the file and see if they're the same.,

Comment: @HosseinHeydari I get '/home/pi/ss', and '/home/pi/ss/python_files/user'

Comment: how you are creating directory path to access file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to this section https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

> Optionally, you can use a converter to specify the type of the argument like **<converter:variable_name >**.

so if you specify `<path:filename>` as converter in your route, that should solve your issue

```
@app.route('/downloads/<path:filename>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

because if NOT explicitly specified, it defaults to `string` converter and it will accept **any text without a slash** that's why you got the error

```
"GET /downloads/python_files/user/file.py HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a life savor! I'm new to the stack overflow and have a question, am i suppose to just show your answer and leave my question the same or update mine with the correct way to do it?

Comment: @TheAdmin on Stackoverflow you asked a question and you mostly got answer(s) and you don't have to correct your question accordingly because that does not make sens and the answer you got has no reason to be there and probably will be a subject for downvotes (very bad for reputation) .. You may update your question with new elements (in general you titled the new section with UPDATE / EDIT to keep history), to make it clear and concise so you can get the right answers.